# Making external drive accessible from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I wish to connect my WD 2TB drive to a Humax HD-foxT2 to play files created on Ubuntu. If I format the drive FAT32 no problems, except the restrictions of file size of FAT32 is a problem, and the Humax apparently uses Ext3 format.

So I formatted the drive in Ext3 using Ubuntu, but Humax doesn't recognize it now.

So I reformatted the drive using the Humax Ext3.  The Humax device now recognizes it but Ubuntu says I do not have permission to write to it then.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! You have it formatted (check) in a format the Humax can read (check) and now need to be able to write to it. Well, then, mount the drive in Ubuntu then from a terminal window on your Ubuntu box, please run

> sudo chmod -R 646 ***/path/to/mountpoint***

where /path/to/mountpoint is the path to the drive, such as /dev/sdb

If you are uncertain as to its name, run

> sudo lshw -C disk

Comment: When I run sudo chmod -r 646 /dev/sdb it says there is no such file or directory?

Comment: >  mount the drive in Ubuntu